# How to flatten a 3d array to 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I need a 3d nested array. How can I flatten that to a 1d array? (Because of performance) I assume, that I need to multiply some stuff etc. but I'm not the greatest mathematician. 
Thanks!

```py
def imgRGB(im):
    width, height = im.size

    #create matrix
    matrix = []
    for i in range(height):
        matrix.append([[0,0,0] for _ in range(width)])

    #get the rgb values
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            r,g,b = im.getpixel((x,y))
            matrix[y][x][0] = r
            matrix[y][x][1] = g
            matrix[y][x][2] = b
    return matrix
```

The pixel values will be compared to other RGB values to find the closest match.

```py
def getNearestColor(rgb):
    a = []
    for i in range(len(rgbValues)):
        d = ((rgbValues[i][0]-rgb[0])*0.3)**2 + ((rgbValues[i][1]-rgb[1])*0.59)**2 + ((rgbValues[i][2]-rgb[2])*0.11)**2
        a.append(d)
    list.sort(a)
    return a[0]
```

Comment: Don't think we have the greatest mind-readers on here either. Could you post a mcve - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: You've tagged NumPy, but your code isn't actually using NumPy. You've created a nested list. NumPy arrays are much more efficient. I don't know what image library you're using, but it likely has a convenient built-in way to get a NumPy array. Also, if you actually do need to flatten your data structure (it sounds like you might not), NumPy arrays have a `flatten` method (or `ravel` if a view is okay).

Comment: When do I have to flatten a data structure? (Performance related)

Comment: I'm using PIL(low)

Comment: You can get a NumPy array from a Pillow image with `numpy.asarray(im)` for a read-only view of the image, or `numpy.array(im)` for a modifiable array backed by a copy of the image's data. As for flattening for performance, there's no general reason to expect flattening data structures to give a meaningful performance improvement. It may help, it may do effectively nothing, or it may even hurt, depending on what you're doing and how low-level implementation details work out. Here, I would say that you should focus on exploiting NumPy before worrying about whether flattening would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ndarray.flatten, in your example it would be `matrix.flatten()`. This returns the flattened version of your matrix. Documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)  also has an example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to do the following:

```
rgbValues = np.array(im).reshape(-1,3)
a = np.sort(np.sum(((rgbValues - rgb)* [0.3, 0.59, 0.11])**2, axis=1))
```

where `rgb` is a list `[r, g, b]` for some values r, g, b.